# Babel: Transpiling failed: Unexpected token using Bootstrap 4 & Codekit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, babeljs, codekit

I'm trying to minify and transpile (with Babel) Bootstrap 4 with CodeKit3.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Babel: Transpiling failed:

SyntaxError: /bootstrap/carousel.js: Unexpected token (219:8)
  217 |     _getConfig(config) {
  218 |       config = {
> 219 |         ...Default,
      |         ^
  220 |         ...config
  221 |       }
  222 |       Util.typeCheckConfig(NAME, config, DefaultType)
```

#### Any idea what this could be?

Here are my settings:

- Check Syntax with: nothing
- Transpile with: Babel
- minify the output
- generate a source map

Then, within Babel

Enabled presets:

- ES2017, ES2016, ES2015

Answer (score 0):

I copied the files in the src folder instead of the dist folder into my project. This seemed to cause the problem.